# Write custom lazy evaluation function like dbplyr to get SQL

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

How can I write the logic to this function which should be able to do 2 things.

```
get_data <- function(database, table=NULL, query=NULL){
  
  rlang::check_required(
    x = database
  )
  
  if(is.null(query) & !is.null(table)){
    
    # check whether code is piped %>% | |>
    query <- dbplyr::sql_render("piped code")
    
  }
  
  return(query)
  
}
```

Accept SQL Query

```
get_data(
  database = "uspto",
  query = "select * from applications where id = 1"
)
```

Recognize that Query is NULL and Table is not NULL so perform some check or pass through to piped code.

```
get_data(
  database = "uspto",
  table = "applications"
) %>%
  filter(id == 1) %>%
  collect()
```

For more context this function will be interacting with an API that accepts SQL as input. There will be a network / microservice layer between the client and the API. So I probably need to do something like below to create a dummy connection which I can then use `dbplyr::sql_render` to get a query string.

```
con <- memdb_frame(
  database,
  .name = table
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this works well enough.

```r
get_data <- function(database, table = NULL, query = NULL) {
  if (is.null(query)) {
    tbl(database, table) 
  } else {
    tbl(database sql(query))
  }
```

With this, you can do

```r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
get_data(con, table = "MyTable") |>
  head() |>
  collect()
get_data(con, query = "select * from MyTable limit 5") |>
  collect()
```

(If you're working with SQL Server, clearly that query should be something like `"select top 5 * from MyTable"`.)

Code golf (shorter code):

```r
get_data <- function(database, table = NULL, query = NULL) tbl(database, if (is.null(table)) sql(query) else table)
```

---

*Edit*. You named your function `get_data` (as did I), so the logical return value should be data. If instead you want to return a *query* to get data, perhaps you really mean:

```r
get_query <- function(database, table = NULL, query = NULL) if (is.null(table)) query else sprintf("select * from [%s].[%s]", database, table)
get_query("quux", table = "sometable")
# [1] "select * from [quux].[sometable]"
get_query("quux", query = "select * from othertable")
# [1] "select * from othertable"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. What this function should do is just return a character string of SQL code. So I kind of understand what you're going at here, but the desired output is different. For example the con portion would need to be within the function both database and table should be character arguments (same with query) as it's interacting with a remote API vs a direct connection. I just don't understand how dbplyr accomplishes this even after staring at code on the dbplyr repo all day. Also for instances where query is supplied it just passes through.

Comment: See my edit @S3AN556, not sure if it is really what you need. Also, you say this should return a character string of SQL code, but your code takes this return value and uses `dplyr::filter` on it, which suggests (again) that it is really _data_. Perhaps you can edit your question to be more clear about what should be happening with the `get_data` function.

Comment: Ya I get that, let me come back when I finish a solution. To get data we must first create a valid SQL string, then pass that to the API which is straight forward. So yes the goal of the function is to return data but where I'm having a hard time is internally creating a SQL query. If the user is familiar with SQL it's very straight forward they just enter a SQL query in the query arg. What I'm still trying to figure out is how I can create a dummy connection and pass through all the piped dplyr R code which then translates it to SQL and sends that.

Comment: isn't `dplyr::show_query()` meant for something like this? I mean ... `tbl(con, "tablename") |> show_query()` returns a (classed) `'select * from "tablename"'` string, and lets you do whatever dplyr-verb thing you want to do before `show_query()`. It seems like you're trying to side-step or reinvent `dbplyr`, which is not a trivial (or, in what I'm seeing, _necessary_) task.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do. I'll likely just change the function around and require query arg which accepts either char of SQL code or typed dplyr code. Then perform some check to see if it's an R code 'expression' or character string.

Comment: I would prefer it to work like dbplyr as I like the way dbplyr works. But it's not trivial as you mention.